Error: EACCES: permission denied When trying to run install sass
I am trying to install Sass but I keep on getting this error:
I have installed node-20.30.1.pkg successfully
If I run : node -v I get - v20.13.1
If I run : npm -v I get - 10.5.2
If I run : sass --version I get - zsh: command not found: sass
This is the complete error code when I run :
npm install -g sass npm ERR! code EACCES npm ERR! syscall mkdir npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass npm ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass' npm ERR!     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:855:10) npm ERR!     at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:546:20 npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0) npm ERR!     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:246:11) npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:165:5) npm ERR!     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:153:5) npm ERR!     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5) npm ERR!  Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass' npm ERR!     at async mkdir (node:internal/fs/promises:855:10) npm ERR!     at async /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:546:20 npm ERR!     at async Promise.allSettled (index 0) npm ERR!     at async [reifyPackages] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:246:11) npm ERR!     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:165:5) npm ERR!     at async Install.exec (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/install.js:153:5) npm ERR!     at async module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cli-entry.js:61:5) { npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sass' npm ERR! } npm ERR!  npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/fernandohernandez/.npm/_logs/2024-05-15T16_53_14_696Z-debug-0.log 

Then I ran :
% npm install node-sass npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs added 211 packages in 1m 21 packages are looking for funding run `npm fund` for details

Already tried some codes like the ones mentioned before and :
% npm install sass                 added 17 packages, and audited 229 packages in 2s 24 packages are looking for funding   `run npm` 0 fund for details found 0 vulnerabilities

Then I tried :
% sass --version zsh: command not found: sass


Have you tried installing sass with sudo npm install -g sass?
